# .bashrc function implementing grepall

Tags: unix, grep, bash, bash-function

I have 2 bash functions catall and grepall

`catall` works fine,  catting every file it finds with the file name printed first, then the content and a new line

```
catall ()
{
  find . -name $1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; cat %; echo"" '
}


grepall ()
{
  find . -name $1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; cat % | grep $2; echo"" '
}
```

But `grepall` doesn't work,  is should do the same as `catall` but with a grep stage on the content of the file

Why is `$2` not sub'ed

Can you make this grepall work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because **you are forking a new shell process** using `sh -c` and all the variable of parent shell are not available in child shell unless you **export** them.

Use this function to make it work:

```
grepall () {
   export p="$2"; find . -name $1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; grep "$p" %; echo "" ';
}
```

It works now because we are creating an exported variable `p` which becomes available in sub shell also.

Since you are forking a new shell anyway you don't really need to call `xargsa` as `find` can do the job for you:

```
grepall () {
   export p="$2"; find . -name $1 -exec sh -c 'echo $1; grep "$p" $1; echo "" ' - {} \;;
}
```

Comment: nice one, just in time to look at my boring test results

Comment: You'll probably want to `unset p` so you don't pollute the environment of the rest of the script. Or, make the env assignment temporary with `find . -name "$1" | p="$2" xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; grep "$p" %; echo "" '` -- don't forget to quote `"$1"`

Comment: last thought: keep using `$2` in the sh script, but pass the function's parameters to the shell: `grepall () { find . -name "$1" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; grep "$2" %; echo' _ "$@"; }`